# How to send Vue form input to Adonis controller using an http request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, adonis.js

So, my Vue component asks for the user to input his email. I'm using `v-model` for data binding.

```
<template>
    <input v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    <button class="tiny">Send</button>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                email: ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My `MailController` in Adonis should be able to receive the user's email as input. I imagined something like this:

```
'use strict';

class MailController {
    *mail (request, response) {
     const email = request.input('email');
    }
}
```

What should be the correct way of getting `email`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) npm install vue-resource --save

2.) In your vue's main js file

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');

Vue.use(VueResource);
```

3.) Change your component file like this

```
<template>
    <input v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    <button @click="submit()" class="tiny">Send</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                email: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            submit: function() {
                this.$http.post('/your-url', {email: this.email})
                    .then(
                        (response) => {
                            console.log(response);
                        },

                        (error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```